Definition of Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator
In the definition of Hilbert Schmidt integral operator, we require the kernel $K(\cdot,\cdot)$ to be defined on $L^2(X\times X)$. I don't quite understand this restriction. Can we allow $K$ defined on $L^2(X\times Y)$ for $X \neq Y$? In that case, do we still have similar properties?
For example, for the original definition, we have the following singular value decomposition of $K$ as
$$K(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda_k \phi_k(x_1)\psi_k(x_2)$$
where $\lambda_k$ is the singular value of operator H-S operator $T$.
Do we still have the above decomposition if $K$ is on $L^2(X\times Y)$?

The singular value decomposition result (as well as plenty of other properties) is still true. You just get an operator from $L^2(Y)$ to $L^2(X)$, is all. Usually, Hilbert-Schmidt operators only refer to those that act on a single Hilbert space, which is probably the reason for the restricted definition.
